# I am trying to host my react website on netlify but this npm install error comes

Tags: reactjs, npm, netlify, netlify-cli

If I run the `npm run build` command locally and drag and drop the `build` folder in netlify, then it is hosted but it gives this big error.

When I try continuous deployment from my github repository.
This is the error showed in the beginning

```
11:51:47 PM: npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
11:54:08 PM: npm ERR! code 1
11:54:08 PM: npm ERR! path /opt/build/repo/node_modules/node-sass
11:54:08 PM: npm ERR! command failed
11:54:08 PM: npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
11:54:08 PM: npm ERR! Building: /opt/buildhome/.nvm/versions/node/v16.8.0/bin/node /opt/build/repo/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
11:54:08 PM: npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/node-sass/build'
11:54:08 PM: npm ERR!   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/include/node -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/src -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/config -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/uv/include -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/zlib -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp
11:54:08 PM: npm ERR!   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/include/node -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/src -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/config -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/uv/include -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/zlib -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o ../src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.cpp
11:54:08 PM: npm ERR!   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/include/node -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/src -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/config -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/uv/include -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/zlib -I/opt/buildhome/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/backtrace.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/backtrace.o ../src/libsass/src/backtrace.cpp
```

it ends here

```
11:54:08 PM: npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.8.0
11:54:08 PM: npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
11:54:08 PM: npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
11:54:08 PM: npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
11:54:08 PM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
11:54:08 PM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2021-08-27T18_24_08_951Z-debug.log
11:54:09 PM: Error during NPM install
11:54:09 PM: Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
11:54:09 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
11:54:09 PM: Finished processing build request in 3m28.53038114s
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KGLOJHqNMg&t=393s this tutorial would help you I guess.

Comment: `npm run build`
`npm install netlify-cli -g`
`netlify deploy`
And sometimes we need to write a rule in _redirects `/*    /index.html  200`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've encountered the same problem today. I realised Netlify is now using node 16.x by default, which is incompatible with node-sass and other dependencies.

You can force a node version on your Netlify environment by going to **"Deploy Settings" > "Environment" > "Edit variables"** and by adding **NODE_VERSION = [version number]** (for example 14 to run node latest 14.x).

See https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/manage-dependencies/.

Comment: or u can create .node-variable file which contains a version number (14) for example at the root of your app

Comment: this answer is great

Answer (score 0):

You can create NPM_FLAGS in the environmental variables to use custom flags on your npm install command.
Variable Name `NPM_FLAGS`, Value: `-f`.
https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/manage-dependencies/