# Can't create Vue project with node-sass

Tags: node.js, vue-cli, node-sass

Just trying to create a with `vue create project-name`. I include CSS Pre-processors, but I can only successfully create the project with dart-sass, as selecting node-sass gives an error, i.e.:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\[username]\Documents\vuengo\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\[username]\Documents\vuengo\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\[username]\\Documents\\vuengo\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.8.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\[username]\Documents\vuengo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\[username]\Documents\vuengo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\[username]\Documents\vuengo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\[username]\Documents\vuengo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\[username]\Documents\vuengo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\[username]\Documents\vuengo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\[username]\Documents\vuengo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\[username]\Documents\vuengo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\[username]\Documents\vuengo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\[username]\Documents\vuengo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\[username]\Documents\vuengo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\[username]\Documents\vuengo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\[username]\\Documents\\vuengo\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\[username]\Documents\vuengo\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-05T16_28_29_162Z-debug.log
ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error --legacy-peer-deps
```

I've tried everything: updating vue, npm, node.js; setting useTaobaoRegistry to false; cache clean --force, etc etc. Not sure what the issue is / how to read the log. I see it's referring to "python2", when I have python3 installed, is that (part of) the problem? Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Yeah, had the same issue. Per this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68976148/how-to-fix-this-node-sass-build-error-on-netlify, use  sass - sass-loader. https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader

Comment: @RizaKhan, hero, thanks. I had no issue setting up the project with dart-sass, but this tutorial I was following was using node-sass. Wasted too many hours trying to make it work!

Answer (score 0):

Due to compatibility issues with the Node version (this is especially evident when you try and push a Vue app to Netlify) you are better off using sass - [sass-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader).